# Angular issue after upgrade version 16 on production

Tags: angular

```
main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasAttribute')
    at dc (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:1038118)
    at vM (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:1085062)
    at Tp (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:1084035)
    at Object.H_ (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:1084839)
    at template (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:209400)
    at op (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:1063267)
    at Sm (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:1070968)
    at D_ (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:1070856)
    at T_ (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:1071172)
    at Sm (main.1e8412d016703b17.js:1:1071183)
```

I have issue after upgrade angular version 15 to version 16. My previous version I'm using angular Service Worker, SSR, Prismjs and after I upgrade version I got below issue that cannot find the root cause since my localhost development no issue at all. @everyone could you help me please I'm sucked almost 1 week already?

Comment: Did you check your code for `hasAttribute`?

Comment: None of my components are using ```hasAttribute```. I only use ```window```, ```document```, and ```localStorage```.

Comment: Then you'll have to run `ng build --configuration development`, check the call stack in the error message (which you posted but with production config), and see which external library is causing the issue

Comment: Finally, you save me. I tried to remove all unused third-party libraries and clear CDN cloudflare cached now my website was upgraded to the new version . Thanks ! https://www.kamsantutorial.com